# React-Typescript edit list

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, use-state, react-typescript

I am using React-TypeScript to create a list of employees, edit and delete them. However my edit button does not do anything on click. Any idea on how I can fix this problem?

I have used the same code for the "Delete" function and works perfectly. Following are my two react-typescript files which I have my codes written in and I also have an app.tsx file which all of these are being imported in it.

**`CreateEmployee.tsx`**

```
import React, { useState, FC, ChangeEvent } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { IEmployee } from "../../Interfaces";
import EmployeeList from "./EmployeeList";

export const CreateEmployee: FC = () => {
  const [employeeName, setEmployeeName] = useState<string>("");
  const [employeeId, setEmployeeId] = useState<any>("");
  const [employeeList, setEmployeeList] = useState<IEmployee[]>([]);

//   get the data from the input and add it to the state
  const handleChange = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void => {
    if (event.target.name === "employeename") {
      setEmployeeName(event.target.value);
    } else {
      setEmployeeId(event.target.value);
    }
  };

// add id and name to the employee list
  const addEmployee = (): void => {
    const newEmployee = {
      employeeId: employeeId,
      employeeName: employeeName,
    };

 setEmployeeList([...employeeList, newEmployee]);
    setEmployeeName("");
    setEmployeeId("");
  };

 // delete employee from the list
  const deleteEmployee = (employeeNameToDelete: string): void => {
    setEmployeeList(
      employeeList.filter(
        (employee) => employee.employeeName !== employeeNameToDelete
      )
    );
  };

// edit employee name and id in the list
  const editEmployee = (
    employeeNameToEdit: string,
    employeeIdToEdit: string
  ): void => {
    setEmployeeList(
      employeeList.map((employee) => {
        if (employee.employeeName === employeeNameToEdit) {
          employee.employeeId = employeeIdToEdit;
        }
        return employee;
      })
    );
  };

 return (


<div>
    <h1>Create Employee</h1>
      <div>
    <label>Employee Id:</label>
    <input
      type="text"
      name="employeeid"
      value={employeeId}
      onChange={(e) => setEmployeeId(e.target.value)}
    />
    <label>Employee Name:</label>
    <input
      type="text"
      name="employeename"
      value={employeeName}
      onChange={(e) => setEmployeeName(e.target.value)}
    />
    <button type="submit" onClick={addEmployee}>
      Submit
    </button>


</div>
  <div>
    <Link to="/employeelist">Employee List</Link>
    <Link to="/engagementList">Engagement List</Link>
  </div>
  <div className="employee-list">
    <h1>Employee List</h1>
    {employeeList.map((employee: IEmployee, key: number) => {
      return (
            <EmployeeList
              key={key}
              employee={employee}
              deleteEmployee={deleteEmployee}
              editEmployee={editEmployee}
            />
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

**EmployeeList.tsx**

```
import React from "react";
import { IEmployee } from "../../Interfaces";
import { CreateEmployee } from "../employeeComponents/CreateEmployee";
interface Props {
  employee: IEmployee;
  deleteEmployee: (employeeNameToDelete: string) => void;
  editEmployee: (employeeNameToEdit: string, employeeIdToEdit: string) => void;
}
export const EmployeeList = ({ employee, deleteEmployee, editEmployee }: Props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="employee-list">
        <div className="content">
          <span>{employee.employeeId}</span>
          <span>{employee.employeeName}</span>
        </div>
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            deleteEmployee(employee.employeeName);
          }}
        >
          Delete
        </button>

        <button
          onClick={() => {
            editEmployee(employee.employeeName, employee.employeeId);
          }}
        >
          Edit
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default EmployeeList;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the current state's value `employeeList` within its setter. Instead of passing an object to `useState`, [you can pass a function instead that takes the old state as a parameter](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates). For example:

```
setEmployeeList((oldEmployeeList) => 
      (oldEmployeeList.map((employee) => {
        if (employee.employeeName === employeeNameToEdit) {
          employee.employeeId = employeeIdToEdit;
        }
        return employee;
      }))
    );
```

Comment: I have only one employeeList, what do you mean with oldEmployeeList?

Comment: The previous value of the state (the old value of employeeList)

Comment: Do I need to define a new state?

Comment: @Sevicode It's *just* a name given to the previous state argument passed during a functional state update.

Comment: Nope it's still not working and I'm not even getting an error.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue of state mutation, you are mutating the employee object you are editing instead of returning a ***new*** employee object reference. Since the specific `employee` object reference doesn't change React is likely bailing on rerendering them since it uses shallow reference equality checks during Reconciliation.

```
const editEmployee = (
  employeeNameToEdit: string,
  employeeIdToEdit: string
): void => {
  setEmployeeList(employeeList => employeeList.map((employee) => {
    if (employee.employeeName === employeeNameToEdit) {
      return {                        // <-- return new object reference
        ...employee,                  // <-- shallow copy previous state
        employeeId: employeeIdToEdit, // <-- set property value
      }
    }
    return employee; // <-- else return previous state
  }));
};
```

Comment: Hey Drew, a newbie is here :D what do you mean by Shallow copy previous state?

Comment: @Sevicode It means copy all the property references into a new array/object. When you `{ ...employee }` you copy the properties but they are copied by reference, in other words, they are still references ***into*** the old object you copied from. After you shallow copy you then create new references, i.e. you set a new `employeeId` property. React works by using shallow reference equality checks, if the reference is still pointing to the same thing as the previous render, it is assumed to have not changed. This is why state mutations are a big deal in React and very anti-pattern.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not that you were mutating the state, your `editEmployee` function was using `setEmployeeList` correctly -- `map` returns a new array, and React was detecting this change and re-rendering the component. You can verify that by inserting `console.log('rendering');` into your `CreateEmployee` function.

The problem was that `editEmployee` was just creating an exact copy of the old `employeeList`.

What you probably want for it to do is to populate the text fields with the edited employee id and name, and then update your employee list when the submit button is clicked.

```
const editEmployee = (
    employeeNameToEdit: string,
    employeeIdToEdit: string
  ): void => {
    // This will put these two items into the text fields for editing
    setEmployeeId(employeeIdToEdit);
    setEmployeeName(employeeNameToEdit);
  };
```

and change `addEmployee` to something like this (you may rename it to `addOrUpdateEmployee`):

```
const addEmployee = (): void => {
    const newEmployee = {
      employeeId: employeeId,
      employeeName: employeeName,
    };

    // Consider it's a new employee if the employee with this employeeId
    // does not exist in the list of employees. 
    // Otherwise, it's an edited employee
    let employeeIndex;
    if (
      employeeList.some((employee, index) => {
        employeeIndex = index;
        return employee.employeeId === employeeId;
      })
    ) {
      // This is not state mutation ...
      employeeList[employeeIndex] = newEmployee;
      // ...because we set it to a copy of the mutated array
      setEmployeeList([...employeeList]);
    } else {
      setEmployeeList([...employeeList, newEmployee]);
    }

    setEmployeeName('');
    setEmployeeId('');
  };
```

The logic to decide if it's a new or edited employee is entirely mine, you should use whatever is appropriate for your  app.

Comment: `employeeList[employeeIndex] = newEmployee;` is quite literally a definition of state mutation, `employeeList` is the current state! The mapping wasn't the state mutation.

Comment: Yes, technically it is, but it has no effect as such, because the new state is set with a copy right after.

Comment: Sure it has effect. You mutated the previous state object, so now React will not see a reference diff in the employee element that was "updated". One of the React Commandments: Thou shalt not mutate state. React is pretty simple on the matter.

Comment: The state here is the whole array (or rather the reference thereof), and the new array is supplied to `setEmployeeList`, since it's a _different_ array reference, React will re-render. You can see it working if you run the code.

Comment: You're not understanding. The array is *obviously* a new array, arrays *also* copy by reference, but that isn't the mutation and isn't the issue. The issue is the mutation of an element *in* the array. State is the entire array, yes, and state is *also* each element of the array, and each property of each element, etc... Yes, there's a new array, and yes, this will trigger React to rerender the array, and as it's doing so will check the reference of each element being mapped to JSX and if the element reference didn't change, it can bail on rerendering, thus you won't see the change in the UI.

Comment: I get your point, but I don't believe it will go inside the array and check every element. I think it only compares the array reference -- you said it yourself it is a shallow comparison. What I see (experimentally) is that when state is changed like this: `setEmployeeList([...employeeList]);`, the entire list of `<EmployeeList>` components is re-rendered -- each of them is, regardless whether it maps to changed or unchanged element in the `employeeList` array.

Comment: Yes, the entire array is *necessarily* rerendered. React needs to do this recursively on the component's entire subtree to figure out what actually changed and what needs to be committed to the DOM. It's when React is mapping the elements in the array to children that it does an equality check and if the individual element still refers to the same element it did on the previous render (*because mutation*), it assumes nothing changed and bails on rerendering the child. Here "render" isn't the "render to the DOM" part it is actually the "render to the VirtualDOM" to see what actually changed.

Comment: Sometimes the mutation is benign and you do actually see what you wanted updated, sometimes there are adverse effects and things get really wonky. Either way, state mutations should be avoided at all times.